# After 30 seconds from the current time, display a notification that 30 seconds have passed

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, time, set

I need to make a page, with time, and change the time every 5 seconds, and after 30 seconds I need to display a notification that 30 seconds have passed

```js
function showClock(){
  var d=new Date();
  var hours=d.getHours();
  var minutes=d.getMinutes();
  var seconds=d.getSeconds();
  var clock=document.getElementById("clock");
  clock.innerHTML=`<h1>${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds}</h1>`;
  
  }
 setInterval(showClock,1000);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
 <section id="main"></section>
 <section id="clock"></section>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please make an effort of trying to make it first. You've already made the clock working, so what is keeping you from making the rest? Whenever you encounter any problems, come back and we can help you.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier I need to add 30 seconds from the current time, and if the current time is equal to the time after 30 seconds, display a notification, but I need to take the time, but how can I take it if it is always to setInterval

Comment: Add a variable **outside** the `showClock` function which stores the current time. Let's say `var now = new Date();`. That date will not change. Compare `now` with `d` inside your `showClock` function to see how much time has passed since `now`.

Comment: Just use `setTimeout(function, delay)` where `delay` is in milliseconds. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give it a try next time ...

```js
let start = (new Date()).getTime();

function showClock(){
    var d = new Date();
    var hours = d.getHours();
    var minutes = d.getMinutes();
    var seconds=d.getSeconds();
    console.log(`${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds}`);
    if(d.getTime() - start >= 1000 * 30) {
     console.log('30 sec');
        start = d.getTime();
    }
}

setInterval(showClock, 5000);
```